# **Edit** How to get variable/values From main method / void to set it on another project

Tags: java, string, get

I'm Trying to get from a void method / main method variables that i have there.

Let me put an example.

```
public class Test{    
   static int ten = 10;

public static void main(String[] args){

    if(something.equals(something)){
      ten = 10; <--------- i want to get that value 
    }      
}
```

So i tried this:

```
public static int getTen(){    
return ten;
}
```

This works only if it is in the main class I want to use it in other functions with that value.

**EDIT**

Lets say i have another class called Test2

```
public class Test2{

public static void main(String[] args){

here i want to get the ten value from Test1 (other class) but i just can't get it.

}

}
```

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by "this works only if it on the main method"? Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem, and clearly describe the expected behaviour vs the actual behaviour.

Comment: if you try to get variable ten in other method, was there an error?

Comment: You cannot use `ten` since it is not global between all classes. However, `Test.ten` will give you the static variable ten in the class Test.

Comment: Can you give me code structure? Together with your said other function within the class

Comment: @Pphoenix I'd say `ten` is not _visible_ globally :)

Comment: @$Pphoenix, hi. can't we call the static variable without class name inside static method?

Comment: As was already said, please provide more information on the exact problem you have. Just to note: you can't "get" local variables that have been declared inside a method, but in your case the variable is declared outside the methods so it should be accessible.

Comment: @SilverBullet: If you are in a method in the class where ten exists (that is Test), you can use ten directly. Otherwise you have to specify which class ten belongs to.

Comment: [Is this what you want](http://ideone.com/E6UZTX)?

Comment: @user3742672 Access it by using the pattern classname.variablename. In your case `Test1.ten`.

Comment: Yes it works. but now i got another problem how do i do it in another project i mean get the ten value and set it at another project

Comment: @user3742672: I do not think that is possible. You probably want to look over your code because project dependencies like the one you described are not something you would like to have.

Comment: Another project or another module?

Comment: Java project and android project

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want fetch value of ten then you can easily pass the variable as function argument with new function for eg.

```
getValue(ten);
```

call this function in the main function and access it outside the main function

```
function getValue(<variable name>){
// print here variable or use it

}
```

Comment: Why would you pass the variable as an argument? Or rather, how do you propose that the value is used? As it is now, you do not need your getValue function as ten already knows its own value.